Labeling puzzle in a bipartite graph
Consider a bipartite graph with vertex set $V_1, V_2$. We have $\forall v\in V_1, \, d(v) = 3$ and $\forall v \in V_2, \, d(v) = 1$.
Nodes of $V_2$ are in groups of $k\ge 2$ nodes, $V_2^1, V_2^2, \dots, V_2^{|V_2|/k}$. Nodes of $V_2$ are initially equipped with a label $\ell(v)$ in $\{0,1\}$ with the following rule:
(P1) $\forall v, v'\in V_2^i, \, \ell(v) = \ell(v')$ (all nodes in the same group have the same label)
Then we extend the labeling $\ell$ to $V_1$ using the following rule:
(P2) $\forall v \in V_1,$ if all neighbors of $v$ have the same label, $v$ is assigned the opposite label. Else, any label will fit.
Question: Given any labeling of $V_2$ respecting (P1), under what conditions on $k, |V_1|$ and $|V_2|$ we can be sure than there exist a list of distinct vertices of $V_1$ $(a_1, a'_1, \dots, a_t, a'_t)$ can be such that at least one couple $(a_i, a'_i)$ must have the same label? Note that the edges of the graph may be arranged as we like.
Exemple 1: with $k\ge 6$ this is trivial. Take a graph with $k=6$, $|V_2|=6$ and $|V_1| = 2$. Whatever are the edges of the graph are, all vertices of $V_1$ are connected to vertices having the same label, hence all the (two) nodes of $V_1$ must have the same label.
For what I do, $k \ge 6$ is currently irrealistic. I only have values of $k \le 4$. However I suspect that using multiple groups (even if the vertices of different groups are assigned different labels!) may help. For instance:
Example 2: Assume k = 3, $V_1 = M$ and $|V_2| = 3M $ and that only $j$ groups of $V_2$ are using the label $1^{[1]}$; $M -j$ groups using label $0$. Then there are $3j$ edges connected to a vertex labeled $0$. Hence if we can somehow make sure that $|V_1| = M > 3j + 2$, there is at least $2$ nodes of $V_1$ that are neighbors to vertices labelled only $0$ and hence must be labelled $1$. By making $j/M$ smaller, we increase the proportion of vertices of $V_1$ that must take label $1$. When $M > 3j + M/2 +1$, we have more than half of the nodes of $V_1$ that must have label $0$. Hence if we taking any pairing of the nodes of $V_1$, there must be one that must have the same labeling; whatever the edges of the graph looks like.
$[1]:$ this is not a realistic assumption to the problem; just an observation. We should expect groups to be labeled by an adversary; hence (I suppose) the nodes of $V_2$ using label $0$ are about the same number as the ones using label $1$.
